# How to get the coordinate of a point in a svg path in c++

Tags: c++, svg

I am trying to implement the animations presented in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qgreAUpPwM)
In order to do so I need to parse a svg path into a set of points.
More precisely, given a svg path I need to get the coordinate of the point that is in some fraction of the curve. For example the coordinate of the point that is located 50% in length from the beginning of the curve to the end.

I have only found solutions for this in javascript and python but I need it in c++ (since I implemented all the graphics in c++ opengl)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing is using the solution I found in python and run the python script in c++

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).